# Taking the input as a comma separated list from a user

Tags: ruby, arrays, input

this is my code to return the elements that are present
exactly once in the array

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
p a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1}
# >> [1, 4, 5]
```

can anyone please suggest how to take the array as keyboard input from user??

Comment: Check out the `highline` gem. You could use it directly or read the source to see how it handles array input.

Answer (score 1):

```ruby
print "Enter an array: "
STDOUT.flush
arr = STDIN.gets.chomp.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)
# Enter an array: 1,2,2,3,3,4,5 <ENTER>
arr # => [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty concise way of collecting a set amount of input into an array:

```
n = 7
a = n.times.collect { gets.chomp.to_i }
```

Then you can use your existing code on `a`.

```
irb(main):022:0> a = n.times.collect{gets.chomp.to_i}
1
2
2
3
3
4
5
=> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):023:0> a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1}
=> [1, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below way:

```
s=gets.chomp
a = s.split("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gets` method to get a string from standard input.  (It's short for "get string"!)
`chomp` removes trailing whitespace, i.e. the newline character that results from pressing enter at the end of your input.

So, calling `str = gets.chomp` and entering `1 2 2 3 3 4 5` at the prompt will set `str` to `"1 2 2 3 3 4 5"`.  Then, just use `str.split` to convert it to an array.